# Adding label(object name) to an Instance object

Tags: java, dataset, instance-variables, sparse-matrix

I created a SparseInstace object using JavaML library, I put some values into that instance but I could not find a solution to assign label on it. For example, the instance is created like

```
{{2=1.0, 4=2.2};null}
```

I want to add specific string value instead of that "null" area. Here is my code:

```
package helloworld;

import java.io.IOException;
import net.sf.javaml.core.Dataset;
import net.sf.javaml.core.DefaultDataset;
import net.sf.javaml.core.Instance;
import net.sf.javaml.core.SparseInstance;
import net.sf.javaml.matrix.Matrix;
import net.sf.javaml.tools.InstanceTools;
import net.sf.javaml.tools.data.FileHandler;

public class WekaT2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {

    Dataset data = new DefaultDataset();
    Instance tmpInstance = new SparseInstance();

        tmpInstance.put(2, 1.0);
        tmpInstance.put(4, 2.2);
        data.add(tmpInstance);       
    }
}
```

http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/api/0.1.7/net/sf/javaml/core/SparseInstance.html

How can I add these labels(object names) into the instaces?

Comment: Do you mean a "class label", as in the classification of a sample in machine learning terminology? Or do you mean an "instance name" so that you can recognize the instance later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to set is called the class label or class value as it is stated in the documentation. You can use  the following method 
`setClassValue(java.lang.Object value)` 
Sample usage would be

```
    Instance tmpInstance = new SparseInstance();
    tmpInstance.put(2, 1.0);
    tmpInstance.put(4, 2.2);
    tmpInstance.setClassValue("positive");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following constructor:

```
public SparseInstance(int noAttributes,
          double defaultValue,
          java.lang.Object classValue)
```

and use an object to specify the label, it can be anything like a JLabel, String, JButton

for example:

```
Instance tmpInstance = new SparseInstance();

    tmpInstance.put(2, 1.0, "myLabel");
```

Greetings

Comment: This way is not true. Put function does not take arguments like these.

Comment: Ok, you have reason, I look that you are casting a SpareInstance into an Instance, maybe, you could work with the SparseInstace. Like it:
SparseInstance tmpInstance = new SparseInstance();

    tmpInstance.put(2, 1.0, "myLabel");